# CSS: 50% Transparent (Opacity) with a solid border

Tags: css

Is it possible with just CSS to have a white background color and then have 50% transparncy with:

`.transparent_class {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}`

and still have a solid white border?

Comment: make sure if you use `rgba` as stated below, you also use `rgb` for browsers that don't support it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`opacity` applies to the whole element. You can wrap the initial element with a parent element and put a border, or you can use `rgba` and apply your opacity to the background specifically, instead of the entire element.

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 4):

```
.transparent_class { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); border: 1px solid #FFF; }
```